# How to change table width using css

Tags: css

Html

```
<table style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>


 <tr>
    <td>blablabla</td>
      <td>blablabla</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
      <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the table width to 600px. I couldnt figure out the selector for changing width.
Please help , i am learning css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this

**HTML**

```
<table style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>


 <tr>
    <td>blablabla</td>
      <td>blablabla</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
      <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  width:600px!important;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank You ! I wasnt using !important 
It was so easy , i dont know why people downvote it ! :p

Comment: if necessary than only use `!important` if not than don't it is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Change the width value in the style attribute.

```
 <table style="width: 600px;">
```

yields a table that is 600px wide.

Comment: You want to change the CSS width using JavaScript? Why didn't your write that in your question?

Comment: Have i mentioned anywhere using javascript? i clearly wrote using css.
btw i got it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this -

```
table [style]{width:600px !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is specified inline right there in your code.

```
<table style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>
```

change this

```
<table style='width: 600px; border: 1px solid black;'>
```

Alternatively

Use a class in your table and  use the selector in your css file.

```
<table class="tbl" style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;'>
```

CSS

```
.tbl{width:600px!important} /*!important override inline css 150px*/
```

If you can remove the inline css used in table, you need not to use `!important` like this-

```
<table class='tbl'>
```

CSS

```
.tbl{width:600px}
```

Comment: Ops , No i dont want to change it from html for some reason , can i change it through css?

Comment: Hey Thank you.
Class thing worked for me :) 
But using table {width: 600px !important;} also worked :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To those who width !important didnt work, try also changing min-width and setting it to !important.

```
.myCssTable { 
width: 80% !important;
min-width: 80% !important;
}
```